# How to handle DeviceNotRegistered error using expo-server-sdk-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, expo

I built a push notification system on my backend using [expo-server-sdk-node](https://github.com/expo/expo-server-sdk-node). When I want to send notifications, I lookup the expoPushToken in my database. The docs states the following error(s) should be handled:

> DeviceNotRegistered: the device cannot receive push notifications
> anymore and you should stop sending messages to the corresponding Expo
> push token.

However, I am unsure how to handle this error since there are no direct pushTokens available in the error message. See the following example:

```
[{
    status: 'error',
    message: '"ExponentPushToken[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]" is not a registered push notification recipient',
    details: { error: 'DeviceNotRegistered' }
}]
```

This device should now be removed from my database, but to do that I need the `ExponentPushToken[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]` value. And because the notifications are sent in batches I lose the reference to the user. What is the proper way to do this?

I thought of the following two ways:

1: Just `split(")` and filter the value, but this depends on the error message.

2: Loop over all my pushTokens, and find where `includes(originalValue)` in `message`, but this would mean I'd have to loop over an excessive amount of users every time it fails.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and here's what I did.

Considering this code

```js
for (let chunk of chunks) {
    try {
      let ticketChunk = await expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync(chunk);
      console.log(ticketChunk);
      tickets.push(...ticketChunk);

      // If a ticket contains an error code in ticket.details.error
      // 
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

- Once I send a batch of notifications (100 most likely).
- I loop through the tickets, if `ticket.status === 'error'` and check for `ticket.details.error === 'DeviceNotRegistered'` as in the code above.
- Since the order of sent notifications is the order in which the response tickets are received.
- Using the current index of the tickets loop, I can access the token at the same index in the chunk I sent.

```js
for (let chunk of chunks) {
    try {
      let ticketChunk = await expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync(chunk);
      tickets.push(...ticketChunk);

      // If a ticket contains an error code in ticket.details.error
      let ticketIndex = 0;
      for (let ticket of tickets) {
          if (ticket.status === 'error' && ticket.details.error === 'DeviceNotRegistered') {
             // Get the expo token from the `chunk` using `ticketIndex`
             // Unsubscribe the token or do whatever you want to
          }

          ticketIndex++;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

**NB:** The code might contain syntax errors, it's the idea I am trying to pass across. I did the same thing with php

Answer (score 0):

It's not documented behaviour (at least I didn't found it in the documentation), but in the ticket error response I can see the `expoPushToken` in the `details` object. See the screenshot attached:

[image]